# Oracle sql - get months id between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have date range eg. '2021-01-05' and '2021-02-10'. Two months January and February.

Need resaults:

```
Months
------
1
2
```

Comment: Don't you want to include the year in your results? What if the date range is from 2020-10-01 to 2021-02-10, would you only want to show 10, 11, 12, 1, 2? If so, you probably want the months in that order? Or doesn't that matter?

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner  Good question!  I didn't think about it. I need this definitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to iterate through the months. This is done with a recursive query in SQL:

```
with months (month_start_date) as
(
  select trunc(:start_date, 'month') from mytable
  union all
  select month_start_date + interval '1' month
  from months
  where month_start_date < trunc(:end_date, 'month')
)
select
  extract(year from month_start_date) as year,
  extract(month from month_start_date) as month
from months
order by month_start_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXTRACT function that Oracle has to achieve this. In your case it should look something like:

```
SELECT EXTRACT (month FROM date_column) as "Months"
```

For more information about this function you can check out documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm).